# On RecyclerView scroll random checkbox selected in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, android-recyclerview

*Note: There are solutions for this issue in stackoverflow but all are written in java

In Recyclerview implemented checkbox OnCheckedChangeListener as follows, problem is when i scroll recyclerview then random checkbox is selected.

```
class ScSerialAdapter(
    private val scSerialNumberList: List<String>,
    private val selectedSerialNumberList: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf<String>()
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ScSerialAdapter.ScLocationListViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ScLocationListViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.stock_serials_list_item, parent, false)
        return ScLocationListViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ScLocationListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.cbSelected.isChecked = false
        val currentSerialNo = this.scSerialNumberList[position]

        for (item in selectedSerialNumberList) {
            if (item == currentSerialNo) {
                holder.cbSelected.isChecked = true
                break
            }
        }
        holder.cbSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                selectedSerialNumberList.add(this.scSerialNumberList[position])
                Log.e("selectedSerialNumber",selectedSerialNumberList.size.toString())
            } else {
                Log.e("SelectedSerialNumber",selectedSerialNumberList.size.toString())
                selectedSerialNumberList.remove(this.scSerialNumberList[position])
            }
        }

        if (scSerialNumberList != null) {
            holder.tvSerial.text = scSerialNumberList[position].toString()
        } else {
            holder.tvSerial.text = "-"
        }
    }

    fun listOfSelectedValues(): List<String> {
        return selectedSerialNumberList
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return scSerialNumberList.size
    }

    inner class ScLocationListViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val tvSerial: TextView = itemView.tv_serial
        val cbSelected: CheckBox = itemView.cb_selected
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the checkbox value every time the `onBindViewHolder()` get called with a new row in the `RecyclerView`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PickListViewHolder, position: Int) {

    if (selectedSerialNumberList.contains(this.scSerialNumberList[position])) {
        holder.cbSelected.isChecked = true
    } else {
        holder.cbSelected.isChecked = false
    }


    holder.cbSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
            selectedSerialNumberList.add(this.scSerialNumberList[position])
        } else {
            selectedSerialNumberList.remove(this.scSerialNumberList[position])
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE

Try to iterate on the list and check if the serial number exist.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PickListViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.cbSelected.isChecked = false
    val currentSerialNo = this.scSerialNumberList[position]

    for (item in selectedSerialNumberList) {
        if (item == currentSerialNo) {
            holder.cbSelected.isChecked = true
            break
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: it is clearing selected checkbox, I mean i have selected one checkBox from recyclerview then i did scrolling. now checkbox is unselected.

Comment: same issue, after scroll checkbox is unselected.

Comment: Updated question with total adapter class

Answer (score 0):

In onBindViewHolder made following changes, It worked

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ScLocationListViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.cbSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
    holder.cbSelected.isChecked = selectedSerialNumberList.contains(this.scSerialNumberList[position])
    holder.cbSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
            selectedSerialNumberList.add(this.scSerialNumberList[position])
            Log.e("selectedSerialNumber", selectedSerialNumberList.size.toString())
        } else {
            Log.e("SelectedSerialNumber", selectedSerialNumberList.size.toString())
            selectedSerialNumberList.remove(this.scSerialNumberList[position])
        }
    }

    if (scSerialNumberList != null) {
        holder.tvSerial.text = scSerialNumberList[position].toString()
    } else {
        holder.tvSerial.text = "-"
    }
}
```